# If I sleep in one bed, then in a separate bed and then remove it, what will happen to my spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As the title suggests, if I have one bed set up in my base, then go adventuring and bring a bed with me, will my spawn change back to the original bed location each time I pick up the bed I just slept in?

Comment: Only one spawn point is preserved per character - there's no place to store your *previous* bed. However, if you're not averse to using mods, OpenBlocks has a great item, the sleeping bag. It's easy to make and it allows you to sleep anywhere *without* changing your spawn point. And it will be picked up automatically when you wake up :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your spawn point will reset to the default location - what it was when you first created the world, and will get the following message when you die:

[image]